# How to pivot_wider while preserving duplicate column values?

Tags: r, pivot, reshape, tibble

looking for some help on this maybe basic issue. Suppose I have the following:

```
tibble(
  x= c("a","a","b","b","b","b"),
  y= c(1,2,1,2,1,2)
)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# x         y
# <chr> <dbl>
#  1 a         1
#  2 a         2
#  3 b         1
#  4 b         2
#  5 b         1
#  6 b         2
```

I would like to transform to the following tibble:

```
tibble(
  x= c("a","b","b"),
  y.1= c("1","1","1"),
  y.2= c("2","2","2")
)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# x     y.1   y.2  
# <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 a     1     2    
# 2 b     1     2    
# 3 b     1     2
```

What's the best way to achieve this? I tried to use tidyr::pivot_wider but I couldn't figure it out without preserving the x column's two "b" values.

Answer (score 0):

Given the current structure, one possible approach is to use vector recycling

```
library(tidyverse)
df = tibble(
  x= c("a","a","b","b","b","b"),
  y= c(1,2,1,2,1,2)
)

df %>%
  summarise(
    x = x[c(T, F)],
    y.1 = y[c(T, F)],
    y.2 = y[c(F, T)]
  )

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   x       y.1   y.2
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1     2
#> 2 b         1     2
#> 3 b         1     2
```

Although this could break if data is not in the proper sequence.

Comment: What if the y value could be more than just 1 or 2? e.g. y could be 1-4?

Comment: @acko you mean you want to extend it to `y.3`, `y.4` etc?

Comment: yes exactly - in this case, I know that y can only go up to y.4

Comment: @acko although not elegant, `df2 %>% summarise(bind_cols(x = x[c(T, F, F, F)], apply(diag(4) == 1, 1, function(x) y[x]) %>% as_tibble(.name_repair = ~paste0("y.", 1:4))))` - the vector recycling by placing a `T` in the position you want, then repeating a number of `F` until the length of a full observation. That assumes that there are at least 4 observations, and may be troublesome if `NA`s are present. Check for example `x = 1:5; x[NA]` to see why.